Hot tub plug is smoking
My hot tub plug is smoking.  Do you think I would need to replace the whole control board, or just the plug?

To burn like that, you need loose connection or too many amps.  A proper size and correct breaker should trip if too many amps.  Electronics/control boards usually do not like heat, so replacement might be needed also.

that does not look like a plug

Thanks for the comments.

Your "line in" terminal block is completely fried. Along with it are a few components to the right and above it. Anything below it would also be damaged beyond repair. There are also some circuit paths that are probably destroyed due to the excessive heat. I would say the board needs replacement. You can see the extent of the damage by looking at a new 56297 board, see photo below from spa parts experts who I am not affiliated with in any way. A new board goes for about 280 bucks.


Full disclosure.  I used a heavy duty SOOW extension cord to plug it in when it overheated.  I read now that an extension cord is a terrible idea for a hot tub.  But I don't understand why.  Can someone tell me why the extension cord fried everything?

@user1260251  Extension cords are not designed/constructed for permanent use. The male and female ends are the weak points.  The hot tubs are usually sent up to run continuously  or at least for hours at a time. This puts a strain on the extension cord parts and the contact points can lose their grip.  This dosen't appear to be the case in your situation. Your failure looks like  loose connection on the terminal block that probably cooked for a long time before finally failing.
